# How do I create an "if and" statement to conditionally format a column of cells using xlsxwriter in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

This isn't working (obviously), so i'm wondering if there are any suggestions. Thank you.

The goals: 
- If AA2 > 0 and AB2 < 0, then format cells in column A with formatc3. 
- If AA2 < 0 and AB2 > 0, then format cells in column A with formatc3.

```
worksheet.conditional_format('A2:A2100', {'type':   'formula',
                                        'criteria': '=AND($AA2>0,$AB2<0)',
                                        'format':   formatc3})

worksheet.conditional_format('A2:A2100', {'type':   'formula',
                                        'criteria': '=AND($AA2<0,$AB2>0)',
                                        'format':   formatc3})
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it right, you miss one small thing in the excel formula, they should start from the first row and not the second. Also no need to write two different statements as your conditions could be nested in just one, it's more efficient and readable. In general try to reproduce your desired output manually in excel, then it's easy to convert it to xlsxwriter's syntax.

Here is a working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Col1': [2, 3, -2, 5],
        'Col2': [-5, 6, 7, -8],
        'Col3': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

green = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#C6EFCE'})

worksheet.conditional_format('C1:C1048576', {'type': 'formula',
                            'criteria': '=OR(AND($A1>0,$B1<0),AND($A1<0,$B1>0))',
                            'format': green})

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: "*In general try to reproduce your desired output manually in excel, then it's easy to convert it to xlsxwriter's syntax.*" - I know we aren't supposed to say "good answer" but that is 100% the correct strategy to resolving conditional formatting issues in XlsxWriter, and I'm the author.